What is the pitch and roll in a tiltmeter sensor?
I wonder if you could help me to understand what the pitch and roll mean for an tiltmeter sensor? I have tiltmeter data and I don´t understand at all how it works. If you can recommend literature on it, and regarding its use in seismology and volcanology, that would be great.
Also I would like to know the difference between a tiltmeter and a inclinometer?
Thanks a lot.


It's simply the measurement of incline in the x and y horizontal directions:
Roll is the angle created by the slope $\frac z y$
Pitch is the angle created by the slope $\frac z x$
A tilt meter and inclinometer are different names for the same sensor.
